# Temperature and Humidity Sensor TinyShield (No device found on com5)

Tags: arduino-ide, temperature-sensor

Hi i have recently started working on a Temperature and Humidity Sensor TinyShield (ASD2511-R-T) and faced the issue as shown in the image below: No device found on com5.

[image]

I have followed the tutorial as shown in the TinyShield webpage and worked through the steps. 1) Installed the Arduino IDE, 2) Installed the Si7021 Arduino Library, 3)Download the .zip file of the example program and open it in the Arduino IDE.

This is the following example code provided by the tutorial.

```
/*
  TinyCircuits Si7020 Temperature and Humidity Sensor TinyShield Example Sketch

  This demo shows the bare minimum to read temperature and humidity data from 
  the Si7020 sensor using the Si7020 library written by Marcus Sorensen.

  This example is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  Written 20 March 2016
  By Ben Rose
  Modified 07 January 2019
  By Hunter Hykes

  https://TinyCircuits.com
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <SI7021.h>

SI7021 sensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.print("Initializing sensor... ");
  if(!sensor.begin()){
    Serial.println("Sensor not found!");
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println("Success!");
}

void loop()
{
  int celcius=sensor.getCelsiusHundredths()/100;
  int relativeHumidity=sensor.getHumidityPercent();
  Serial.print(celcius);
  Serial.print(" deg Celsius\t");
  Serial.print(relativeHumidity);
  Serial.println("% relative humidity");

  delay(500);
}
```

However, when I proceed to upload the program, the following error had occurred. This is the first time i am working on a TinyShield product.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Do let me know if i need to provide any further information.

The options for COM 5 the only one avaliable.
[image]

Comment: why did you choose COM5 as the serial port?

Comment: The error indicate that your Arduino is NOT connected to COM5 !

Comment: Hi, that was the only options available in the port option when i connected it. I have added the screenshot in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below was the issue, i was using the wrong broad and processor.

Thanks for the help!

[image]